How can I pass post parameters from JS to MVC controller?
I have the following JS code:
const data = await fetch("/api/database/sample", 
{ 
    method: "post", 
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8" },
    body: JSON.stringify({ names: ['ahmad', 'mutawa'], age: 22 })

});


This code successfully triggers the following method in a Mvc Controller (in a .net core 8 application):
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class DatabaseController: Controller
{
    [HttpPost("sample")]
    public IActionResult Sample(string[] names, int age)
    {
        // names = []    // why ????
        // age   = 0     
        return Json(/* some object array */);
    }
}

The only issue is, the parameters names and age are set to default 'empty or nullfor names, and0forage`.

I changed the Content-Type to urlencoded-form, and that allowed me to set the age successfully, but the names array is treated as a single string variable, meaning all values within the array are inserted into the first element.
How do I resolve this issue?

If you don't want use dto to bind the data, you can change your backend code like below to fix the issue.
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace WebApplication9.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class DatabaseController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost("sample")]
        public IActionResult Sample(Dictionary<string, object> payload)
        {
            // names = []    // why ????
            // age   = 0     

            var names = payload["names"] as JArray; 
            var age = Convert.ToInt32(payload["age"]);
            return Ok(new { names, age });

        }
     }
}


Recommended Solution
Use FromBody attribute to bind the data.
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace WebApplication9.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class DatabaseController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost("sample")]
        public IActionResult Sample([FromBody] SampleRequest request)
        {
            var names = request.Names;  
            var age = request.Age;      
            return Ok(names);
        }

        public class SampleRequest
        {
            public string[] Names { get; set; }
            public int Age { get; set; }
        }
    }
}

